# Jquery from submit does not send input values to controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, laravel

I have this hidden form

```
<form method="POST" action="reviews/rate" class="hidden">
      {{ csrf_field() }}
      <input type="text" name="id" value="{{ $review->id }}">
</form>
```

Radio button

```
        <fieldset class="rating" data-rating="{{$review->getAverage()}}" >
            <input type="radio" id="star{{$review->id}}_5" class="rate" name="rating{{encrypt($review->id)}}" value="5" /><label class = "star" for="star{{$review->id}}_5" title="Awesome - 5 stars"></label>
            <input type="radio" id="star{{$review->id}}_4" class="rate" name="rating{{encrypt($review->id)}}" value="4" /><label class = "star" for="star{{$review->id}}_4" title="Pretty good - 4 stars"></label>
            <input type="radio" id="star{{$review->id}}_3" class="rate" name="rating{{encrypt($review->id)}}" value="3" /><label class = "star" for="star{{$review->id}}_3" title="Meh - 3 stars"></label>
            <input type="radio" id="star{{$review->id}}_2" class="rate" name="rating{{encrypt($review->id)}}" value="2" /><label class = "star" for="star{{$review->id}}_2" title="Kinda bad - 2 stars"></label>
            <input type="radio" id="star{{$review->id}}_1" class="rate" name="rating{{encrypt($review->id)}}" value="1" /><label class = "star" for="star{{$review->id}}_1" title="Sucks big time - 1 star"></label>
        </fieldset>
```

which style is

```
.hidden {Vardas
  display: none;
}
```

and jQuery function which submits form

```
$('.rate').on('click', function(e){
$('.hidden').append(this).submit();
});
```

.rate is star radio button. Using its event listener I append radio input to hidden form and  submit the form.

Here is the output of the request in laravel controller

```
Request {#42 ▼
  #json: null
  #convertedFiles: null
  #userResolver: Closure {#139 ▶}
  #routeResolver: Closure {#141 ▶}
  +attributes: ParameterBag {#44 ▼
    #parameters: []
  }
  +request: ParameterBag {#43 ▼
    #parameters: array:3 [▼
      "_token" => "uVJUAwdUVhukLLFMgy9FIBlGh9LsY836uhjoA0EO"
      "id" => "28"
      "ratingeyJpdiI6Ijc1R2wyNXYzMVd1QVwvNGZQVERwMXp3PT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6IlFRSklDK1NlUlFkcEZMWHVtZWpnNFE9PSIsIm1hYyI6IjhhM2FjODZhZWY0YzNlN2U1ZDYxMTQ0OTljMGViYTg3MmZhMWQ4MGMyOTcxYTgxMzAzMGNiNjgwNzE1YTJmNmQifQ==" => "5"
    ]
  }
  +query: ParameterBag {#50 ▶}
  +server: ServerBag {#46 ▶}
  +files: FileBag {#47 ▶}
  +cookies: ParameterBag {#45 ▶}
  +headers: HeaderBag {#48 ▶}
  #content: null
  #languages: null
  #charsets: null
  #encodings: null
  #acceptableContentTypes: null
  #pathInfo: "/reviews/rate"
  #requestUri: "/reviews/rate"
  #baseUrl: ""
  #basePath: null
  #method: "POST"
  #format: null
  #session: Store {#169 ▶}
  #locale: null
  #defaultLocale: "en"
  -isHostValid: true
  -isForwardedValid: true
  basePath: ""
  format: "html"
}
```

At least the id field value should be posted with request because I can see it is in the form input through inspect but its always "28" which is wrong.

EDIT. I see now the rate is posted correct but id still is not.

EDIT. Id is always "28" even thought the value is different in the input everytime

Comment: Did you check the value of `$review->id ` before the form is submitted?

Comment: I did not, but I can see it is set correctly and then it gets its lost in the jQuery function becoming "28" or null.

Comment: Kindly post the code for the html containing the appended radio input.

Comment: @avonnadozie edited post

Comment: I can't really find anything in the codes you posted that explains why you always get '28' as value for `id`. You can try debugging line by line to see at which point the value of `id` changes to 28.